# Python: urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: authenticationrequired

Tags: python, urllib2

I was trying to get a web page, but got into this problem. I've looked up some references, and this is what I've done so far:

```py
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user = 'myuserID'
password = "mypassword"

ip = sys.argv[1]
url = "http://www.websites.com/" + ip

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

header = {
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate'
    }
html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, header))
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# some if else function afterwards #
```

When I try to run the script, it shows this kind of error:

```
python checker.py 8.8.8.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checker.py", line 34, in <module>
    html = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url, None, header))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 469, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 656, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: authenticationrequired
```

But if I opened the page or other web page, and manually enter my credential, this script works fine after that. Am I missing something?

Just to add, my current network are using McAfee web gateway device. So sometimes we need to enter our credential to proceed browsing the net. Our user/pass are integrated with Active Directory. Is that may cause the issue?

Comment: Does http://www.websites.com/ require authentication?

Comment: By how you name it it seems the security is some form of .htaccess instead of a real basicauth system. I don't think those two are compatible. That's practically what the error is indirectly saying.

Comment: @LutzHorn, as far that I know, that website does not require any authentication.

Comment: Well, you get a `HTTP Error 401`. This indicates that the URL *does* require authentication. Since you don't tell us the real URL you try, we can not help you here.

Comment: @Allendar I just remember that my network are using McAfee web gateway device that use Active Directory to authenticate. Is that may cause the issues?

Comment: the authentication could be not using HTTP Basic Auth. Check with Firebug/Chromebug what headers does it send

Comment: @Xander89 could be that Active Directory uses some kind of SAMBA authentication system. Check the Windows Server documentation to see what technology/method it uses for web-access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work really well (taken from another thread)

```
import urllib2
import base64
import sys

user = 'myuserID'
password = "mypassword"
ip = sys.argv[1]
url = "http://www.websites.com/" + ip
request = urllib2.Request(url)
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (user, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Or you may use `requests`:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

user = 'myuserID'
password = "mypassword"
ip = sys.argv[1]
url = "http://www.websites.com/" + ip
res=requests.get(url , auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
print res.text
```

Comment: the first code works like a charm. I replace my code with yours and it works fine. Thanks Alexey! :)

Comment: I had 3 different URLs I was calling with the same code as in the question. 2 gave me this error, one didn't. I switch to this code and all 3 work. I'd like to know why the other code didn't work though.